# Static Framework Optional Dependencies iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

We have a static framework that we have built and it depends upon an SDK 
Currently, the user would add our framework and the dependency SDK and everything would work fine. The SDK has come out with a new version which has a new interface.

We want the user to be able to add our framework and either the old or new SDK and I'm not sure how to do this without creating multiple targets which we would rather not do. With the way I have it setup the user has to add our SDK and both the old and new SDK's.

I have a protocol `SDKProtocol` which is implemented by two classes `NewSDKServices` and `OldSDKServices`.

`NewSDKServices` won't compile unless the new SDK is present and `OldSDKServices` won't compile unless the old SDK is present. I figure this could work since it is a precompiled framework and we can decide at runtime which to use.

Then I'd like to be able to do something like this, maybe with a `ifdef` to import and initialize the correct service.

```
if (useNewSDK) {
    _sdkService = [[NewSDKServices alloc] init];
} else {
    _sdkService = [[OldSDKServices alloc] init];
}
```

When I try to run an app with our framework and only one of the other SDK's present it fails and tells me it's finding undefined symbols. I've thought about using reflection `NSClassFromString` but I'd prefer not to.

Both SDK's have a few headers and a `.a` and we distribute our framework as .a